# Electron App which uses GraphicsMagick to resize an image

Tags: image, resize, imagemagick, electron, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to use [GraphicsMagick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) to resize images inside an Electron app I'm building.

The flow is (described with psuedo code):

```
1 - Read EXIF data from image file (async, callback with step 2)
2 - Rename the file (async, callback with step 3)
3 - Create thumbnail (using imagemagick).
```

Steps 1 and 2 are working properly - which means I'm able to read the EXIF data, and also renaming the files. But the last callback, to step 3, is returning an error.

Here is the code of step 2 and step 3:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , gm = require('gm');

...
...
...
...now inside step 1 callback:

    var randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
    console.log(randomString);
    var newFileName = path + '\\' + userName + '_' + randomString + getExtension(file);
    var thumbFileName = path + '\\thumbs\\' + userName + '_' + randomString + '_thumb' + getExtension(file);


    fs.rename(path + '\\' + file, newFileName, function (err) {                             
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(newFileName);
        gm(newFileName)
        .resizeExact(240, 240)
        .write(thumbFileName, function (err) {
            if (!err) console.log(thumbFileName + 'done');
            else console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I checked and verified the following:

`path + '\\' + file` is getting renamed to `newFileName` with no issues.

`thumbFileName` is correct, as `path + '\\thumbs\\'` exist (I'm able to open the path in Windows Explorer).

The error message I'm getting for each file is:

```
C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\test\testImage [998 years, 6 months, and 12 days]_kwink.JPG
C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\test\testImage [998 years, 5 months, and 23 days]_z34mj.JPG

Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\test\testImage [998 years, 6 months, and 12 days]_kwink.JPG" "-resize" "240x240!" "C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\test\thumbs\testImage [998 years, 6 months, and 12 days]_kwink_thumb.JPG" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\renaME\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:232)
        at emitOne (events.js:96)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188)
        at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\renaME\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:36)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215)
    script.js:68 Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\test\testImage [998 years, 5 months, and 23 days]_z34mj.JPG" "-resize" "240x240!" "C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\test\thumbs\testImage [998 years, 5 months, and 23 days]_z34mj_thumb.JPG" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\renaME\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:232)
        at emitOne (events.js:96)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188)
        at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\AlonAd\Desktop\dev\project\renaME\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:36)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215)
```

I've double checked, both of the images mentioned in the console are there, with the exact names being logged in the console, so its not path or filename problem, and `thumbs` directory is also there.

I'm starting to suspect it might be an `Electron<->GraphicsMagick` issue, or maybe you see here something else ?

Comment: Small thought: the console output says `this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found`, maybe GM wasn't installed properly?

Comment: That was also my first thought, to verify it I've changed the paths of the files to wrong ones to create a controlled error and see if I get a specific message, but it was the same message - what brings me to think it is a general one. In addition, I've installed using `npm` exactly as mentioned in the docs (including the pre requisite).

Comment: Okay, that's quite funny and I have no idea what could cause this behaviour. (Maybe you file an issue?)